# Can I have two where clauses in my SQL Query so I can add $_SESSION?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have  a sql query and I want it to also only show the information for the logged in user. I was thinking is it possible for me to add another where clause to the query to add in: username = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'

Here is my query:

```
$sql= "
SELECT 
 user.username,books.bid,name,authors,edition,
 status,approve,issue,issue_book.return 
FROM user 
inner join issue_book ON user.username=issue_book.username 
inner join books ON issue_book.bid=books.bid 
WHERE issue_book.approve ='$exp'
ORDER BY `issue_book`.`return` DESC";
```

Anyone know how I would write this to achieve what I want above?

Here is my entire code:

```
<!-- Updated navbar for logged in user -->
<?php
if($_SESSION['login_user'])
{
  include "navbar_user.php";
}
?>

<h2 style = "text-align: center; padding: 2%;">Your Expired Books </h2>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
{
$exp = 'EXPIRED';

$session_value = $_SESSION['login_user'];

$sql= "SELECT user.username,books.bid,name,authors,edition,status,approve,issue,issue_book.return FROM user inner join issue_book 
ON user.username=issue_book.username inner join books ON issue_book.bid=books.bid WHERE issue_book.approve ='$exp' AND username = ".$_SESSION['login_user']."
ORDER BY `issue_book`.`return` DESC";

$res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0)
{
    echo "You have no expired books.";
}
else
{ 

    ?>
    <table class = 'table table-bordered'>
<tr style='background-color: #abb79b; color: white;'>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>BID</th>
    <th>Book Name</th>
    <th>Authors Name</th>
    <th>Edition</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Return Date</th>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    ?>
    <tr style = 'background-color: white;'>
        <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['bid'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['authors'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['edition'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['return'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
}
}
else
{
echo "</br></br></br>";
echo "<h2><b>";
echo "Please login first.";
echo "</b></h2>";
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: I _think_ you are just asking about `AND`, so, `WHERE abc=1 AND xyz=2`, unless I’m missing something?

Comment: @ChrisHaas when I do that I get this error Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given and its on this line:   if(mysqli_num_rows($res)==0)

Comment: @DJDog that just means the query failed. post in the entirety what you have tried. if you typed `username` without the table qualifier, this would likely return an ambiguity error, I imagine there's a reason you qualified `user.username` earlier in the query

Comment: Can this page viewed by logged in users and users that are not logged in?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I've added in my entire code so you can see what I have done.

Comment: @Dula yes this page can only be viewed by logged in users.

Comment: Two things: (1) your code is wide open to SQL injections. Please don't put this on the Internet. (2) You're missing quotes around the username: `AND username = '". $session_value ."'` (variable used since it was set) 

Comment: @matigo the quotes didn't help my error

Comment: Then you have more than one thing to look at. You're probably getting an "ambiguous" error because `username` is defined in multiple tables, but you're not stating *which one* to use in your `WHERE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

use and(&&) operator
It may allow to add as many condition as use want

Comment: Changed AND to && in my query and im still getting the error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given

Comment: So that means my query is failing? What is wrong with my query though can you see the problem?

Comment: As per documentation of PHP: mysql_query - Manual[^] - when the query statement fails the call returns the boolean value FALSE.
First check out that your query is working or not?
just print it and see what  data it is giving

Comment: syntax flow its fine
 just check out yours data is fine or not?
let debug for starting for the base

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DJDog Don't get into bad habits using && and || as they are non-standard and have finally been [deprecated in MySQL 8.0.17](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and)

Comment: try to add single quotes for the username check. like this username = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."'
rest of the query as is